# Instagram API and Pagination

Tags: api, pagination, instagram, instagram-api

I can't get all images using Instagram API, Pagination seems to be working somehow different and I can't understand it yet

I use request:
[https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=*TOKEN*](https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=_TOKEN_)

and can get first 20 photos:

```
...
{
  "attribution": null,
  "tags": [
    "beautiful",
    "instalife",
    "picoftheday",
    "beauty",
    "instalike",
    "gf",
    "traveling",
    "instatravel",
    "vsco",
    "tourism",
    "\u0438\u0441\u043f\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f",
    "travelphoto",
    "vscogood",
    "instafollow",
    "travel",
    "\u0433\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0430\u0434\u0430",
    "amazing",
    "vscocam",
    "followme",
    "photooftheday"
  ],
  "type": "image",
  "location": null,
  "comments": {
    "count": 1
  },
  "filter": "Normal",
  "created_time": "1442825564",
  "link": "https:\/\/instagram.com\/p\/74vm3GOCEn\/",
  "likes": {
    "count": 18
  },
  "images": {
    "low_resolution": {
      "url": "https:\/\/scontent.cdninstagram.com\/hphotos-xap1\/t51.2885-15\/s320x320\/e15\/11934647_531283580370186_1131008999_n.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 320
    },
    "thumbnail": {
      "url": "https:\/\/scontent.cdninstagram.com\/hphotos-xap1\/t51.2885-15\/s150x150\/e15\/11934647_531283580370186_1131008999_n.jpg",
      "width": 150,
      "height": 150
    },
    "standard_resolution": {
      "url": "https:\/\/scontent.cdninstagram.com\/hphotos-xap1\/t51.2885-15\/e15\/11934647_531283580370186_1131008999_n.jpg",
      "width": 612,
      "height": 612
    }
  },
  "users_in_photo": [

  ],
  "caption": {
    "created_time": "1442825564",
    "text": "#\u0413\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0430\u0434\u0430 #\u0418\u0441\u043f\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f #photooftheday #picoftheday #instalike #followme #vscogood #vscocam #vsco #instafollow #travel #traveling #instatravel #instalife #tourism #gf #beauty #beautiful #amazing #travelphoto",
    "from": {
      "username": "solotravel_me",
      "profile_picture": "https:\/\/igcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/t51.2885-19\/11282631_115839268762391_863189534_a.jpg",
      "id": "736938591",
      "full_name": "and"
    },
    "id": "1078821495951073761"
  },
  "user_has_liked": false,
  "id": "1078821489441513767_736938591",
  "user": {
    "username": "solotravel_me",
    "profile_picture": "https:\/\/igcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-xaf1\/t51.2885-19\/11282631_115839268762391_863189534_a.jpg",
    "id": "736938591",
    "full_name": "and"
  }
}
...
```

after that I'm trying use max_id parameter, but I'm not sure which ID I need to use
I tried id of the photo, photo_user id, I even tried timestamp (found this idea on some forum), but every time I receive only first 20 photos

example:
[https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=*TOKEN*&max_id=1078821495951073761](https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=_TOKEN_&max_id=1078821495951073761)

Comment: just use the pagination.next_url has worked perfectly for last 5 years

Comment: forgot to tell, pagination object is empty
`{
  "pagination": {
    
  },
  "meta": {
    "code": 200
  },
  "data": [
  ...
  ]
}`

Comment: but there are much more, than just 20 photos

Comment: then there may not be more than 20 photos, login and check on http://gramfeed.com

Comment: but there is. 377 photos in this account. gramfeed shows them all. But I still have no pagination object

Comment: if I will use &count=(<20) any number, less than 20, then I will get pagination object. But self/media/recent returns only 20 images, no more. But on this account there is definitely much more images

Comment: don't put &count= param

Comment: I used it only for example, to show that pagination is working only for the first 20 photos, but I can't get more

Comment: may be you are in sandbox mode ?

Comment: it's embarrassing, but yes :| I used client's credentials for this job, and this app is in sandbox mode

Comment: i'm not sure, but may be api is limited in sandbox mode

Comment: yes, this is exactly the problem here

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was having the same problem with the empty pagination object while the account actually had more photos.

And just to make things clear here. This question is answered in the comments of the origial question.

There is nothing in the pagination object because the app is in sandbox mode and app's in sandbox mode never returns more than 20 posts(photos).

Comment: Hi, do you know if it is still possible to use pagination and get all the media? I am developing an app which will depend on this functionality but so far I have the app in sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use this API for getting all posts of the user:

```
https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/feed/user/{user_id}
```

For pagination, the parameter name is `max_id`

Pass `max_id` which you have returned in this API's response.

Hope this helps !!